# Use Map constructor in Typescript with initialized values

Tags: typescript

The type definition for Map is as follows

```
interface MapConstructor {
    new <K, V>(): Map<K, V>;
    new <K, V>(iterable: IterableShim<[K, V]>): Map<K, V>;
    prototype: Map<any, any>;
}
```

I want to use the 2nd constructor `new <K, V>(iterable: IterableShim<[K, V]>): Map<K, V>;`

I have a type I've defined `type ChangeMap = { [key: string]: Array<string> };` which is used as follows

```
let changeMap: ChangeMap = { A: ["Car", "Boat"], B: ["Plane", "Rocket"] };
```

I want to create a `Map<number, ChangeMap>` which I can do easily enough but I'm stuck as to how to structure the data I want to initialize my `Map` with

```
public changeOptions = new Map<number, ChangeMap>( ... what goes here ... ?)
```

Is this possible or do I need to initialize my `Map` without values and then call `changeOptions.set(1, changeMap);` to give it values?

--- EDIT #1

To answer @Paarth's question below, the `number` keys in the `changeOptions` `Map` are identifiers for other objects in the domain.

Assume I have a class of Option defined as follows

```
class Option {
    id: number;
    name: string;
}
```

The `id` of a given `Option` instance would be the key for the `changeOptions` `Map`. There are a limited predefined set of `Options` based on business rules for the domain. Assume for this question there are 3 `Option` instances with `id` values of `2, 10, 34`, so I want those to be the keys of the `changeOptions` `Map`

Comment: Where do the numbers (first parameter in your set call) come from?

Comment: @Paarth The number keys for the `changeOptions` `Map` are IDs for other objects in the domain. Depending on that ID I want to use a different `ChangeMap`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The syntax is:

```
  let changeOptions = new Map<number, ChangeMap>([[2, changeMap], [10, anotherChangeMap], [34, thirdChangeMap]]);
```

Comment: Confirmed - example here https://tsplay.dev/WkEyDN
Thanks! 

Answer (score 2):

Where do the numbers come from? Are they just an order based on an array?

If so...

```
let changeMaps = ...

public changeOptions = new Map<number, ChangeMap>(changeMaps.map((v,i) => [i+1,v] as [number, ChangeMap]));
```

You don't actually need the `<number, ChangeMap>` anymore because the expression ends up as a `Array<[number, ChangeMap]>` thanks to the `as [number, ChangeMap]` but it doesn't hurt to have and it's good for documentation.

Breaking it down: If we want to have an iterable set of changes to pass into the map constructor, we need to store them in a collection. That's changeMaps up above, the `...` is for you to fill it out how you wish. The naive form with one item is just `[changeMap]`. We then map that collection to a collection of tuples, including the indices. I used `i+1` because it seemed like you wanted to start with the number 1. That's what gets passed into the map constructor.

Comment: I can't use auto-incrementing indexes as explained in EDIT #1 in my question